# Measuring blinding procedure in a 3 conditions repeated measures experimentation

Tags: chi-squared-test, repeated-measures

I'm confused about what to do, chi-square or something else.
I want to measure the efficiency of my blinding procedure. In my study, each participants received 3 conditions (10Hz, 20Hz, sham). After each session, they were asked if it was a true stimulation or not. Some prefered to answer «i don't know»; so true, false, or DK.

1) What can i do to measure the blinding procedure?
2) Should i consider only the sham condition or all conditions?
3) should i consider the DK answer or consider it as a «bad» answer, as they haven't been able to recognized the right answer. In this case, for exemple, after the 10 hz stimulation; 4 said true, 5 said false, 2 DK; so i'd have 4 recognized and 7 not recognized. Would that be simplify the analysis.

Thank you very much for the one who would help me!!!!
All my respect to people good in stats! haha

Answer (score 0):

1. Depends on what you are trying to answer here, given that you dependent variable is a factor with 3 levels a $\chi^2$ test is probably the easiest option,
2. All the conditions,
3. You should keep all the original levels, DK is a reasonable level just like the other two, you could think of DK as being in between yes and no.

Comment: Many thanks for the answer. So in spss, should i create 3 levels then for each of them, write the answer given by each participants? For exemple, if true stimulation = 1, false = 2, DK = 3, for each variable i'll have ; cond10; 1,1,3,2,2 / cond20; 2,2,1,3,2 / condsham; 3,2,2,1,3 ; then i do a chi square?

Comment: I don't know SPSS so can't help you there, but yes, you would create a factor with 3 levels and then do a $\chi^2$ test on these.